# When I want to switch from A tab to B then it shows blank page using cypress

Tags: cypress, chai, mochawesome

After login when I switch from Tab A to Tab B then it shows blank page,
How i maintain session of Tab A. After performing activity on Tab A, I move to Tab B and start performing activity on Tab B

[image: My Code]

[image: Screen which I want to automate]

Answer (score 2):

If the session has not been created yet, it will run the callback `fn` code, otherwise, it will only restore the session **(and you'll have to visit the page again).**

So, I think changing `before` hook to a `beforeEach` and adding a visit after the login method would work:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  login('user1')
  cy.visit('http://#')
})
```

But this approach will visit the page twice in the first run, to avoid this personally I would use the login with it's code in the `before` hook and restore and visit the page in the `beforeEach`.

```js
const login = ({ sessionId, username, password }) => {
  cy.session(sessionId, () => {
    cy.visit('http://#')
    cy.get('[type=text]').type(username)
    cy.get('[type=password]').type(password)
    cy.get('[type=submit]').click()
  })
}

describe('test', () => {
  const sessionId = 'Login with valid credentials'

  before(() => {
    login({ sessionId, username: 'user1', password: 'Test123' })
  })

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.session(sessionId)
    cy.visit('http://#')
  })

  it('Tab A', () => {
    cy.get('#A').click()
  })

  it('Tab B', () => {
    cy.get('#B').click()
  })
})
```

Please let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: It is also nice to use `login` method as a custom cypress command, please check the docs: https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands

Comment: No, it's not working. I want to start 2nd test case where 1st test case stops.

Comment: So try to define `testIsolation: 'off'` (not sure what version you're using) in cypress.config and use the same code you put at the question, this way Cypress will not clear the page by visiting about:blank before each `it` block.
Should work, but please keep in mind that's not a good practice.